# Is 'et cetera' used in spoken English?

Tags: expressions

I've never heard someone say it. I'm more interested specifically in British English, but also in general.

Comment: Apparently, you've never seen [_The King and I_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JHH6iwgIek).

Comment: @Gnawme Guilty! But it's a musical... it's from 1951...

Comment: ESL: Even my kids understand @Gnawme's witty comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the film's huge popularity made the expression a catch phrase, but I don't have any data to back this up. I just know the first time I saw the movie on TV when I was about seven, I learnt how to say and use this very handy abbreviation. ELU even has a question related [Did "et cetera" gain its popularity from The King and I?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/did-et-cetera-gain-its-popularity-from-the-king-and-i)

Comment: @J.R.  American musicals are generally not popular abroad, with the UK being an exception. Interestingly whenever I've mentioned a 50s musical in Italy I am met by blank stares. Sad but true.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - My kids have seen a handful of musicals from that era, thanks to local high school productions, and movie remakes they've watched on DVDs. Still, I doubt they could recognize or recall too many quotes from _South Pacific, Guys and Dolls, Damn Yankees_ or _Fiddler on the Roof_. However, _"et cetera, et cetera, et cetera"_ seems to be locked into their brains – perhaps because repetition is one of the great teaching mechanisms? So, maybe I should clarify: not all zingers from 50 years ago become commonly known, but this one (the triplet) seems to stand out for some reason.

Comment: Maybe not the quotes but definitely the song titles, have you ever began singing with gusto; "If I were a rich man" to an Italian 15-year-old who obviously thought you had gone crazy? That's happened to me, more than once. :)

Comment: @J.R. Good for them but what are you impaling with 'Even my kids understand Gnawme's witty comment'?

Comment: ESL - You mentioned "But it's a musical... it's from 1951." I'm not 100% sure what that meant, but I guessed that you wondered if a scene from a musical written more than 50 years ago really had anything to do with your question about usage. I simply wanted to mention that even kids born in the 1990's are familiar with that very expression. (As a matter of fact, it's the first thing that popped into my head when I saw the question title.) So, it may not really answer your question per se (which is why it's a comment, not an answer), but it's not merely an irrelevant, outdated factoid, either.

Comment: @J.R. Strange, cause when I was in UK, some people asked me what 'et cetera' means. And I know how to pronounce it properly.  
That's why I asked this question in first place.

Comment: @Mari-LouA et al. As an epilogue, I asked my daughter yesterday, "What's the first thing you think of when you hear the term _et cetera_?" She thought for only an instant, then stood in an audition pose, and said with a smile, "Et cetera, et cetera, et cetera..." As for _If I Were a Rich Man_, yes, we can count that among the small handful of tidbits that are unforgettable. They also remember the name Nicely Nicely from _Guys and Dolls_.

Answer (score 1):

Et Cetera is used in spoken English quite frequently in certain circles.

I will say however, that at least in the US, I have found people to often mispronounce it as "ect cetra". This is because most people that write it out on paper use the shorthand version, "etc...". I contribute that to the reason people don't know how to pronounce it correctly; or in other words, they don't know how to spell it.

Comment: I bet they don't! I bet they say "exetra" without a /t/ in the first cluster.

Comment: "Et cetera" is certainly heard often enough.  I've never heard ect cetra and "expresso" for "espresso" causes my ears to twitch, so it is not a common error in my neighborhood.